# Docker mongodb - how are data only containers portable

Tags: docker, dockerfile, large-data-volumes, dockerhub

How are data only containers portable when they ultimately store data on the host under `/var/lib/docker` ?

Let's say I have this data container on my machine that stores entries into a database. And now let's say someone else 500 miles away wants to use that data container for his database.

How would I give him the container?

Answer (score 1):

This question is hella broad.

So the Docker images are `portable`.  You can start a container, do a bunch of operations like install packages, start services, modify files and then do a:

```
docker commit <container-id> myname/containername:version
docker push <image-id>
```

Then the rest of the world can use your container image if it's pushed to [DockerHub](https://hub.docker.com/). That is if your permissions are public. You can also make your image `private` so that it can be shared by a select group of people. Another alternative is to setup your own [Docker Registry](https://blog.docker.com/2013/07/how-to-use-your-own-registry/) and just push your images to that registry so that it's not widely available to everybody.

If you want to share your `data`. I don't recommend using Docker images, it's just not what it's meant to be.  Say you are using [mysql](https://www.mysql.com/), you can just do a [mysqldump](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/mysqldump.html) of your database and store it in some service like [S3](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/) and then shared it to whoever you want so that they can later import the data into their own containers running mysql.

Hope this helps.